# Creating cmd Process that runs java

Tags: java, c#, process

In my c# code I have

```
 processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("do.cmd");
 processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
 processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

and in my do.cmd I have

```
@echo off
set CONFIG_FILE=./some.properties
set DEFCONFIG_FILE=./more.properties
set EDA_ARGS=-config %CONFIG_FILE% -defaultconfig %DEFCONFIG_FILE%
set JAVA_ARGS=-Xmx256M
set BOOTCLASSPATH=../lib/1.jar;../lib/2.jar;../lib/3.jar;../4.jar;../5.jar
:run_erp
java -Xbootclasspath/p:%BOOTCLASSPATH% %JAVA_ARGS% -jar ../lib/RUNME.jar %EDA_ARGS%
goto end
:end
```

I'm getting an error unable to find RUNME.jar, however if I run the do.cmd manually in a command prompt, it works fine.  But if I create a Process in c# and run it, I get the error above.

So my question is how can I run a cmd in c# equivlantly to running it in a cmd prompt?

Comment: Did you try setting the `WorkingDirectory`?

Comment: What does ../lib/ translate into when running from C#? It makes assumptions about the current directory, which is probably different from the one you have when running do.cmd

Comment: @KirkWoll yes, but i'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe, I think you are on to something, cause I hardcoded some paths into my do.cmd and it was able to find it, so I guess I have to figure out how c# translates those strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by doing three things.

1. changing the object creation to contain only the command (because I set working directory)

   ```
   processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("do.cmd");
   ```
2. setting the working directory to where my `do.cmd` is

   ```
   processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + $"\\somedir\\bin\\";
   ```
3. Setting the `UseShellExecute` to `true`:

   ```
   processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
   ```

Comment: Even though you self-answered, go ahead and mark your answer with the checkmark.